# Intellij IDEA 15 Frameworks detected

Tags: intellij-idea

I had created a Maven profect in Intellij IDEA 15, then I created folders main/webapp/WEB-INF and web.xml in it. Then IDEA says that a framework is detected and I can Setup framework "web". When I created spring-servlet.xml IDEA offered me to setup Spring framework.
What happens when I setup these frameworks?

Comment: Wave you tried setting these frameworks up and seeing for yourself?

Comment: Yep. As I see setting up web framework creates Web module in project structure, sets Web Module Deployment Descriptor Path, Web Resource Directory, Path Relative to Deployment Root Source Roots.

Comment: Setting up Spring Framework creates module "Spring" in Project Structure, where I can see where Spring Application Context, MVC application context and MVC spring servlet context files lay.

Comment: Setting up Web Framework also creates Web exploded artifact. I'm new to Spring and I don' have strong understanding of what are artifacts, Path Relative to Deployment Root, contexts. I saw source folder and Web Resource Directoriy beeing setting up somewhere else. And I don't understand why do we need Spring Module if I already set this information in web.xml.
I wanted first to be sure that I don't miss something about setting frameworks and then I wanted to gain more understanding in questions I've written above.